# The username is not a member of the provider

Tags: electron, electron-builder, apple-id, electron-notarize

I am having trouble with the Electron app notarising using the [electron-notarize](https://github.com/electron/electron-notarize). I have created an app specific password from the https://appleid.apple.com/. In addition, I'm not a part of any team. It's just my personal Apple ID + Developer account as shown in the following screenshot.

[image: Apple ID]

However, I am seeing the following error when I attempt to build the app through [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build).

```sh
1 package(s) were not uploaded because they had problems:
        /var/folders/xw/f3dmryjd1lz27zcc43hs9vbr0000gn/T/B967F8F2-309E-4149-A6FA-2C12F0BDF63F/io.provider.app.itmsp - Error Messages:

2020-03-18 23:58:05.200 altool[11959:306625] *** Error: The username adsfasdfdsa@gmail.com is not a member of the provider. Contact your team admin for assistance. (1296)
```

I have the following code for the electron notarise configuration.

```js
appBundleId: "io.provider.app",
appPath: `${appOutDir}/${appName}.app`,
appleId: "abcadsfdasfds@gmail.com",
appleIdPassword: "xxxxxxxxx",
```

I have also tried using the `ascProvider` in the above configuration rules but didn't have any luck.

```js
ascProvider: "asdfasdfadsfdas@gmail.com"
```

Or

```js
ascProvider: "My Full Name"
```

I am now out of options and idea what I am missing here exactly. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After an hour of investigation, I just realised that I couldn't notarise my app without having the paid $99 apple developer account. So, that's explain why the process was failing when attempting to uploading the app to the apple server for notarisation. However, the error from `xcrun altool` is totally vague as what it says doesn't make sense now.